Setting up IronPython3.4.1 in PyCharm
I have installed IronPython3.4.1 from the windows instalaltion file (.msi) and then I installed PyCharm Community 2024.2.3
Ihave created a new Python project and choose ipy.exe as a system interpreter. I have written a very simple script, just to test it:
import clr

clr.AddReference("System.Windows.Forms")
from System.Windows.Forms import MessageBox, MessageBoxButtons

MessageBox.Show("Hello World!", "Greetings", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel)

But clr, System, MessageBox and MessageBoxButtons are underlined as unresolved references, but when I execute the script everything works as expected. I can see a message box and I can click either OK or Cancel.
How to resolve this issue? This underline and report clr as no module name is really annoying.
